# Possível erro de concordância em notificação de pergunta subjetiva

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Após escrever o título de uma pergunta recebi a seguinte notificação:

[image: Notificação de pergunta subjetiva]

O correto não seria...

> A pergunta que você está fazendo parece ser subjetiva e provavelmente será encerrada.

Ou realmente está correto?

Comment: Se está correta ou não eu não sei, mas me soa natural da forma como está (disclaimer: sô minero)

Comment: Para mim o "deve" soa como se a pergunta já existisse e **deve** ser encerrada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embora, "provavelmente deve ser" soe natural, pelo menos para os brasileiros, concordo que "será" é melhor neste caso.

Na verdade, o termo "provavelmente deve" já me soa semanticamente contraditório. Mas o pior problema está realmente no tempo verbal.

Note que se mudar para "provavelmente vai ser encerrada" já fica um pouco melhor, já que "vai ser" é a forma mais gramaticalmente porca de dizer "será".

Comment: Acho que o tempo verbal em pt castiço seria no subjuntivo: "provavelmente deva". Mas dá mesmo para simplificar, seja com a sugestão do AP, ou ainda algo mais simples: "parece subjetiva e sujeita a fechamento" (acho que hoje as pergunta são consideradas "fechadas", e não "encerradas", né?)

Comment: @bfavaretto neste caso não, porque nós não falamos assim. É mesmo como o utluiz sugeriu. De qualquer forma já está abrasileirado com "você" e "fazendo". Em pt_PT ficava: "A pergunta que está a fazer parece ser subjetiva e provavelmente vai ser fechada"

Comment: Coloquei "ficava" propositadamente :D

Comment: Levantei essa questão pois me pareceu estranho a maneira que está, se for realmente mudar, seria legal algo que fique bom para BR e PT

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não quis dizer que em Portugal se fala assim, acho que me expressei mal. Quis dizer que se for para seguir estritamente o que dizem as gramáticas, seria "provavelmente seja". O melhor pra mim era – :) – "parece subjetiva e sujeita a fechamento".

Comment: @utluiz, devo aceitar a resposta ou aguardar mais membros se manifestarem? Ou talvez deixar a mensagem como está e considerar como resolvido?

Comment: @Mateus Se você achar que minha resposta está suficiente, pode marcar como certa. Vou falar com o Gabe sobre isso, pois ele cuida dessas coisas de tradução. Depois que ele fizer a correção ele marca a pergunta com uma tag para marcá-la como "corrigida" ou "rejeitada", conforme cada caso.